# The workbench failed to connect to the server (Error: WebSocket close with status code 1006) Gitlab Web IDE

Tags: nginx, websocket, gitlab, ubuntu-20.04

Hello I am trying to connect a remote machine to the WEB IDE, but I am getting the following error

`The workbench failed to connect to the server (Error: WebSocket close with status code 1006)`

I am using an ubuntu vps
Use this configuration in nginx

```
server {
server_name remote.demo.com;

location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3443;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
}
```

Also enable Websockets on cloudflare

I followed the steps in this guide:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/remote_development/#generate-lets-encrypt-certificates

Answer (score 0):

I used this way in nginx.conf . Make it success  through WebSocket.

```
location / {
  allow all;
  proxy_pass "IP:PORT";
  proxy_http_version 1.1; #WebSocket
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Nginx as a reverse proxy server? If so, try nginx config as follows:

```
location ~ ${your frontend url pattern} {
  resolver {your DNS server}

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  # trick here, if absent, the server may block the websocket request!.
  proxy_set_header Origin http://${your backend host}/;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  # trick here, consult https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html for Nginx official doc
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;

  proxy_cookie_domain ${your backend host} ${your frontend host};

  proxy_pass ${your backend url pattern};
}
```

config above working for me. my scene：

- code-server: 4.18.0, running in an container of Kubernetes
- nginx:1.9.7, running in an container of another Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

I used this way in nginx.conf . Make it success through WebSocket.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).